# $A=B$, almost everywhere if and only if $\mu(A\Delta B)=0$

Tags: lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

Let $(S,\mathcal{S},µ)$ be a measure space.

We say that $A=B$, almost everywhere (a.e.), for $A,B∈S$ if $\chi_A=\chi_B$, a.e. How do I show that $A=B$ a.e., if and only if $\mu(A\Delta B)=0$

I figure $\Delta$ denotes the symmetric difference: $A\Delta B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$.

what does that tells about $(A\setminus B)=(B\setminus A)$?
How do I get to the wanted conclusion?

Comment: Can you write the set $\left\{x\in S\mid \chi_A\left(x\right)\neq\chi_B\left(x\right)\right\}$ as an expression of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Remember that $\mu (A) = 0 \not \Longrightarrow A = \varnothing$.

Comment: "$(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)=\phi$"  What?  No.  It means $(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$ is a set of measure 0. For example let A = [0,1] and let B=$([0,1]\cap Irrationals)\cup([2,3]\cap \mathbb Q)$.  I'm very rusty on measure theory and not sure how to prove this-- i would have that it was almost a definition.  $(A\setminus B)=(B\setminus A)$ would imply A = B

Comment: @Guy I understand that $x\in S$ if it is only in $A$ or only in $B$. I don't know how to write it.

Comment: @havakok $A\Delta B$.

Comment: Remind me what $\chi_A\left(x\right)$ means.

Comment: Shortcut: $\chi_{A\Delta B}=|\chi_A-\chi_B|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Leftarrow)$If $0=\mu(A\Delta B)=\int \chi_{A\Delta B}d\mu=\int(\chi_A+\chi_B-2\chi_{A\cap B})d\mu$. So $\mu(A)+\mu(B)=2\mu(A\cap B)$. From the fact that $\mu$ is monotonous, it follows that $\mu(A\cap B)\leq \min\{\mu(A),\mu(B)\}$. Therefore $\int\chi_Ad\mu=\mu(A)=\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(B)=\int\chi_Bd\mu$.